# What's wrong with my jQuery code finding the first parent?

Tags: jquery, parent

I'm developing a small app which haves a tree view menu, so this is the html:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 1 </a></li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2 <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.2 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to highlight the clicked li element adding the `.active` class to it. But, when you click on a subelement, I want to highlight also the parent. For example, if you click the `ELEMENT 2.1` I want to highlight also the `ELEMENT 2`.

This is my jQuery code to get, first the clicked element, and then it's li parent (I can't do ir without the `:not` selector for other reasons:

```
$(".sidebar-menu").on("click", "li:not(.treeview)", function(e){
    $(e.delegateTarget).parents("li").first();
}
```

The if statement works as expected, but the second line always give me a `undefined` error in the console.

Comment: $(e.delegateTarget).parents("li").addClass('active'); should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns8t7fje/)**.

You could use the jQuery object `$(this)` that refer to the current clicked element then `addClss()` to add class active class :

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
```

**NOTE :** you have to use `$('li').removeClass('active');` to remove active class from all the other li's`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".sidebar-menu").on("click", "li:not(.treeview)", function(e){
  //remove active class from all the other li's
  $('li').removeClass('active');
 
  $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to the clicked li

  //Add active class to the parent if exist
  if( $(this).parents('li').length > 0)
      $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 1 </a></li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2 <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.2 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't notice that I was using `$(e.delegateTarget)` instead of `$(this)`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

use `$(this)` instead of `$(e.delegateTarget)`

```
$(".sidebar-menu").on("click", "li:not(.treeview)", function(e){
    $(this).parents("li").first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and event stopPropagation:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".sidebar-menu").on("click", "li", function(e){
    $(".sidebar-menu").find('.active').toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).is('li.treeview')) {
      $(e.target).toggleClass('active');
    } else {
      $(e.target).closest("li").toggleClass('active');
      if ($(e.target).closest('.treeview').length == 1) {
        $(e.target).closest('.treeview-menu').prev().toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 1 </a></li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2 <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 2.2 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;"> ELEMENT 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```